# Chrome extension not being added to Chrome browser when using ChromeDriver for Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

I am attempting to open Chrome browser with an extension. Chrome opens, but it doesn't have my extension. Here is my code. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
private IWebDriver GetChromeDriver(BrowserConfigurationOptions browserConfigOptions)
{
    var outPutDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    var chromeDriverPath = Path.GetFullPath(outPutDirectory + @"\Drivers");

    var options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddExtension(outPutDirectory + @"\3.1.5_0.crx");
    options.AddArguments("disable-infobars");
    options.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);
    if (browserConfigOptions.KioskModeForChrome)
        options.AddArgument("--kiosk");

    return new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverPath, options);
}
```

The extension exists in the path where I expect it to be.

- Chrome version: 60
- ChromeDriver v:2.29
- Selenium v: 3.5.2

Comment: are you adding kiosk mode also? Also make sure the path and filenames are correct

Comment: Yes, I am, but kiosk mode doesn't work either. All file paths are correct. That's the first thing I checked.

Comment: Are you sure ChromeDriver 2.29 compatible with Chrome 60?  I use ChromeDriver 2.30 for Chrome 60.  From your code,  all looks good.

Comment: As @yong mentioned you should always use latest chromedriver with newer versions of chrome

Comment: ----------ChromeDriver v2.29 (2017-04-04)----------
Supports Chrome v56-58
Resolved issue 1521: Assignment to Object.prototype.$family causes a crash [['Pri-1']]
Resolved issue 1482: Chromedriver cannot handle the alert generated by onbeforeunload event [['OS-All', 'Pri-2']]
Resolved issue 1315: |switch_to.window| does not visually switch tabs [['OS-All', 'Pri-3']]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that WebDriver 3.5.2 does not support ChromeDriver 2.29. These problems can be resolved if we downgrade to WebDriver 3.4. Then everything works. I logged an issue on their [Github](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4736#event-1262250180) but I believe that backwards compatibility is not expected between WebDriver and older versions of ChromeDriver.